# trying to use VideoCapture and imshow(), raises Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 with OpenCV `2.4.7`, following this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8).

I have spent hours searching the web for solutions, including all of the relevant SO questions.  I have tried:

- the return value of `VideoCapture::open`   is 1
- extending the waitKey() delay to 50ms and later 500ms
- setting the dimensions of the window
- creating another project on Visual C++
- opening an existing image instead of reading from camera (same error)

but no luck, please help!

Here's my code:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat image;

    VideoCapture cap;
    int camOpen = cap.open(CV_CAP_ANY);

    namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true) {
        cap >> image;

        imshow("window", image);

    // delay 33ms
    waitKey(33);        
    }

}
```

As I compiled and ran it, I got the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file ........\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261

Error occurs at the line     `imshow("window", image);`.  When I commented it out, there are no complaints.

---

UPDATES:

A plausible explanation of why this error occured was that my webcam takes time to start, which is why image.empty()  is true initially, hence the abort() function was called to exit the program.

With the code

```
if (!image.empty()) {
    imshow("window", image);
}
```

we can wait for the camera to start

Comment: Not to be a stickler or anything, but if you put `namedWindow("xyz", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)`, it will be much easier for you (and later, others) to read and follow..

Coming to you issue, could put breakpoints after every line and tell me where exactly the issue is occurring..?

Comment: edited question as requested, let me know if any other additional information would be helpful

Comment: had put "xyz" as an example. For this example, you should be putting "window" (t is the name of the window and hence should be same in `namedWindow` and `imshow`.

Comment: Check your webcam settings , whether it works . If you use Skype or other webcam software, check whether it is working .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tried your code and for me it works (it visualizes the current webcam input)!
I ran it on Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with OpenCV 2.4.7.
...
The error occurs because the image is empty, so try this:

```
while (true) {
    cap >> image;

    if(!image.empty()){
        imshow("window", image);
    }

// delay 33ms
waitKey(33);        
}
```

Maybe the first image you receive from your webcam is empty. In this case imshow will not throw an error. So hopefully the next input images are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
int camOpen = cap.open(CV_CAP_ANY);
```

Or you can try changing this:

```
while (true) {
        cap >> image;

        imshow("window", image);

    // delay 33ms
    waitKey(33);        
    }
```

to

```
try
{
     cap >> image;
     imshow("window", image);
     waitKey(33); 
}
catch (Exception& e)
{
    const char* err_msg = e.what();
    std::cout << "exception caught: imshow:\n" << err_msg << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I have seen this in another question and tried it, but the same error persists

Comment: @JohnYeung can you debug it and tell me it happens after which line?

Comment: yep I had this code before, but didn't show it in the question for simplicity and clarity. but pretty much all it did was it printed the error message again

Comment: Can the opencv source be built on any location? I think the main problem lies there. Or it could be a bug on Opencv 2.4.9 ?

Comment: apparently, it worked after cleaning up the compiled files of python.

Answer (score 0):

**Always** check for errors.

You can either enable exception throwing from the `VideoCapture` instance, or you will have to check manually.

If checking manually, there are two places you need to check:

1. `assert(cap.isOpened());` after creating/opening the `VideoCapture` instance. If it could not be opened, there is no exception being raised by that. You have to check and handle this. An assertion suffices but you can handle this more gracefully if you want.
2. `if (image.empty()) break;` after each `cap >> image;`, or `if (!cap.read(image)) break;` *instead of* `cap.read(image);`, because the video stream may have ended or there's some issue with the camera. Again, no automatic exception being thrown. You need to check and handle this. The `read()` may fail intermittently (i.e. next `read()` works again), but that's rare. Usually, once a `read()` fails, all following `read()` calls on that VideoCapture instance will also fail.

There is [**`VideoCapture::setExceptionMode()`**](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#afcab97adfa090883dce5523e9ebcb995), which allows `read()` and `open()` calls to actually **throw exceptions on their own** instead of failing silently. In that case, you still have to catch the exception and inspect it (`e.what()`). If you don't catch and inspect the exception explicitly, the runtime may just print to stderr *that* some exception occurred, but no details on it.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i=0;

while(i<4)

{

VideoCapture cap(0); // force camera to open 4 tiMEs

i++;

}

waitKey(5000); 
VideoCapture cap(0);
int camOpen = cap.open(CV_CAP_ANY);

namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while (true) {
    cap >> image;

    imshow("window", image);
waitKey(33);        
}
```

Do this it will work for you for sure.

Comment: You should elaborate why this works. In fact there isn't a good explanation other than a bug, if it would work but unfortunately it doesn't.