# Why Do I get an Error every time i try to use Open cv's Video Capture it keeps hitting me with the same error in Visual studio

Tags: python

Ive been trying to use the video capture in OpenCV but it keeps hitting me with this error:
`(-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586385/assertion-failure-size-width0-size-height0-in-function-imshow is amost exactly the same as this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assertion failure : size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586385/assertion-failure-size-width0-size-height0-in-function-imshow)