# unable to load picture with opencv with vs2013

Tags: c++, image, opencv, visual-studio-2013

i am reading the Learning CV book, i came across the first example and encounter this problem

Using OPENCV 3.0.0 and VS 2013, all libraries added and checked.

the code is as follows

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
}
```

So after compiling or build, I got a window named Example1, and it is grey, no image in the window.

Is this correct? Or what should I expect to get?

Comment: You provided the proper path to the image you're trying to load as a command-line argument in your debug-configuration, *right* ? Your example is about as stock as you can get: [nearly verbatim](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut1.html) to the tutorial online.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you speedy response. I don't think I do... The difference between my code and the link you gave me is this line, 'cvLoadImage(argv[1])‘ . how do i specify the path to image using my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading the image correctly, i.e. `argv[1]` has an invalid path. You can check this like:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    //IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("path_to_image");

    if (!img)
    {
        std::cout << "Image not loaded";
        return -1;
    }

    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
}
```

You can supply the path also directly in the code like:

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("path_to_image");
```

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342428/5008845) to know why your path may be wrong.

You also shouldn't use old C syntax, but use the C++ syntax. Your example will be like:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    if (!img.data)
    {
        std::cout << "Image not loaded";
        return -1;
    }

    imshow("img", img);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31545237/5008845) to know how to setup Visual Studio correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear if the image is being loaded. OpenCV will silently fail if it can't find the image.

Try

```
    auto img= cv::imread(name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    if (img.data() == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load image" << std::endl;
    }
```