# OpenCV-Python not displaying image

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently following a tutorial on how to use OpenCV with python but something isn't working. When i run this code that should display an image i get this error: `error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:271: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow`

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('C:\Users\Ive\Downloads\7.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Someone already asked this question on here but the answer didn't work for me. The answer was to remove the unnecessary quotes. But i don't have them.

Comment: Try `img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Ive\\Downloads\\7.jpg',0)` (Escape backslash) See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31342428/5008845)

Comment: curious:  Doesn't the python interface require using the `namedWindow` function first to create a window?

Comment: It's working, thanks. But can you explain why is it working?

Comment: As you know, "\n" (new line), "\t" (tab) etc have a well defined meaning. "\U", "\I" etc don't. So your string is ill-formed. Try printing the string with and without escaping backslashes, and you'll see that one is a valid pathname, the other is not.

Comment: ooooohhhhh okay. Thanks

Comment: Photon, namedWindow is used when you want to create a window and assign image to it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes, or your string will be ill-formed.
This will work:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Ive\\Downloads\\7.jpg',0)
```

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342428/5008845) additional information.