# display image in opencv with python

Tags: python, opencv

i am learning openCv with python.i want to display image but the code is not working.. it is not displaying anything rather than errors i searched but problem still same.. i followed solution mentioned here

[OpenCV-Python not displaying image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903416/opencv-python-not-displaying-image)

```
  import cv2
img = cv2.imread("D:\\iki\\images.png", 0)
if img is None:
  print ("The file does not exist")
else:
  cv2.imshow("image", img)
```

but it didnt solve my problem..kindly point out where i am doing mistake would be grateful

error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ATech/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/cc task/FYP_OpenCv/read_show_img.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:625: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'`

Comment: Always check `if img is None`. Try to use the absolute path.

Comment: Did you make sure the image path is correct?

Comment: how could i check that ?

Comment: @DylanRiley  yh path is correct

Comment: I wrote... `if img is None`. Also, I said: try to use the absolute path; did you try?

Comment: Try putting in the full path of the image. Go to the folder where your image is and then copy the path above(to the left of the search bar)

Comment: sure Sir i mentioned full path still its not wrking :(

Comment: Don't paste textual information (e.g. code, error message) as images -- such things can't be searched for, aren't accessible, and people generally aren't interested in retyping it.

Comment: then how could i ask such problem ?

Comment: @sabeenkanwal You should copy the code and the error and **properly format them** when pasting in your question.

Comment: g Sir gona edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your file does exist. Try this:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("./Downloads/2nd-color.png", 0)
if img is None:
  print ("The file does not exist")
else:
  cv2.imshow("image", img)
```

Be aware of the second argument in `imread`. `0` is for grayscale. Have a look at: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image

Hope it helps

Comment: You are welcome. If it answers your question, please mark as answered. Otherwise, comment what is still wrong and we can try to figure that out :)