# In openCV programming by visual studio c++ if i get argc=1 i cant load picture,how can i fix it?

Tags: c++, opencv

I copy this code from openCV2 book and this code have `argc` and `argv` as arguments that I don't know what they are and why assign to 1 (`argc=1`) and  terminate debugging ...my problem that why `argc=1`? And how I can fix it? because my `argc` should be 2 (`argc==2`)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  if ( argc ! = 2 )
  {
    printf( " usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n" );
    return - 1;
  }
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[ 1], 1 );
  if ( ! image.data )
  {
    printf( " No image data \n" );
    return - 1;
  }
  namedWindow( " Display Image" , WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( " Display Image" , image);
  waitKey( 0);
  return 0;
}
```

I try to wrote this code without `argc` and `argv` but the debugger has a runtime error that i think its cause be `argc`.

Comment: You have to tell the command line arguments to pass to main within your debug project properties.

Comment: @saeed masoomi What are you going to change in the program? It is clear written in the program itself how to run it: " usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n".

Comment: @saeed masoomi By the way if it is indeed a code from a book then the book is bad.:) Though as for me then I do not read books. I only see pictures.

Comment: Thanks I try again:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run it by command line, you can call it as

```
DisplayImage "path_to_image"
```

If you want to run from VS, be sure to add the "path_to_image" in your command arguments:

1. PROJECT -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging
2. Put the "path_to_image" in Command Arguments

Be sure that "path_to_image" is a valid path, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31342428/5008845) for reference.

As already pointed out in comments, it's a very bad example!
OpenCV 3.0.0 has also [CommandLineParser](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/command_line_parser.html) for more complex input arguments.