# Cannot read image

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to read an image using `OpenCV`, where I did the following:

```
input_image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
    if(input_image.empty())
    {
        cout<<"Image cannot be read";
        return -1;
    }
```

I'm using `Xcode 6.4`, and would like to pass *two* arguments, one for the input image and another for the output image.

So, I did the following in order to pass the argument:

```
Product --> Scheme --> Edit Scheme...
```

And, under `Arguments`, added two arguments: `image1.png` and `image2.png`.

I had only `image1.png`, which I added to the directory containing `main.cpp`. But, when I try to run the program, the input image seems not to be read, since the above `if-statement` evaluates to true, and I get the error message.

Why is that? What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try printing `argv[1]`? Also, if the executables are generated somewhere else than where the source file is that might be the reason too..

Comment: The files need to be in the application's "working directory", which is not the same as the source directory. There's a setting for it in your project settings.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm really new to this. Is there a reference you recommend for doing that?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31342428/5008845). Most likely you're not passing the correct path. You can try using the full path just to see if you can load the image

Comment: @Simplicity XCode's builtin manual is usually pretty good. It's in the "Help" menu. (I won't recommend googling "xcode working directory" as the results are rubbish, but there's loads of introductions online.)

Comment: @Miki I tried the full-path, but didn't work

Comment: just to narrow down possibilities, try putting the full path in the code as `Mat image = imread("path_to_image");` This should work

Comment: @Mike Yes, having the full path directly in the code made the program work just fine

Comment: Well, actually if your image _can_ be loaded, you just need to look where to put input arguments in your IDE (which I dont know). In VS it would be under "debugger" properties.

Comment: @Miki I tried to enter the full path again as arguments, and it worked just fine! I think the main issue was the ordering of how the arguments were set. Thanks a lot for your support