# cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:325: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I pass the image name as a parameter to this function:

```
def main(imageName):
    image = cv2.imread(imageName)
    cv2.imshow('color_image', image)
    gray_image =  grey(image)
    cv2.imshow("gray_image", gray_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    clahe_image = clahe(gray_image,0)
    cv2.imshow("clahe_image", clahe_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    dst_img = denoise(clahe_image)
    cv2.imshow("dst_img", dst_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    binary_img = threshld(dst_img,0)
    cv2.imshow("binary_img", binary_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    skiw_img = deskew(binary_img)
    cv2.imshow("skiw_img", skiw_img)
    cv2.imwrite("skiw_img.png", skiw_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

then i get that error.but when i execute it without parameter

```
def main():
    image = cv2.imread('e2nn.png')
    cv2.imshow('color_image', image)
    gray_image =  grey(image)
    cv2.imshow("gray_image", gray_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    clahe_image = clahe(gray_image,0)
    cv2.imshow("clahe_image", clahe_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    dst_img = denoise(clahe_image)
    cv2.imshow("dst_img", dst_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    binary_img = threshld(dst_img,0)
    cv2.imshow("binary_img", binary_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    skiw_img = deskew(binary_img)
    cv2.imshow("skiw_img", skiw_img)
    cv2.imwrite("skiw_img.png", skiw_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

i did not get that error and it execute well.

Comment: what are you passing in `imageName` ?

Comment: name of the image (a string)

Comment: You can pass the name if the image and the script lie within the same folder. It is best to pass the entire path of the image.

Comment: I did that. But still  i get same error

Comment: Please show what you passed.

Comment: image name like 'home.jpg'

Comment: Try passing the path as well like: `C:/Users/Jackson/Desktop/home.jpg`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) simple code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341845/opencv-error-assertion-failed-size-width0-size-height0-simple-code)

Comment: Here are about 120 ideas on what the problem might be... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+is%3Aq+%22-215%22+imshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes up when no image (the array containing the image information) reaches the `imshow()` function. This is caused because your `imread()` function is not returning the desired output. Common mistakes include the following:

1. Incorrect Image Name: Check the name of the image right down to the format. Even jpg and jpeg are different.
2. Incorrect Path: In the case that your image is not in the same directory, put the full path to the image. Since you're using Windows, don't forget to change the backslash to forward. Those using Ubuntu should ensure that they put a '\' before home eg `'\home\username\Desktop'`
3. Access Issues: This is more prevalent for linux users but sometime you might not have read access to the image. Try using `chmod 777` and run your code again. Please note that it is advised to change the access back to something more restrictive.