# imshow() giving error in Python for image

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("drop.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow("blue", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The `imshow` function is giving error, the rest of the code is working fine.

Error message:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in
>   cv::imshow, file
>   D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 289
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\D\Desktop\new 
>   2.py", line 6, in 
>       cv2.imshow("image",img) cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.1.0\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:289:
>   error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow

Comment: Show us the error message!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821269/assertion-failed-size-width0-size-height0)

Comment: my guess is that your program is not able to read drop.jpg. Check wether it is in the right directory. Secondly after imread you should verify that your image is reasd successfully then proceed to imwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img=cv2.imread("D:\Matlab\Images\d.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

The above line should be modified as:

```
img=cv2.imread("D:\\Matlab\\Images\\d.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: This solved the issue I was facing. Rookie mistake on my part; I should have been using system agnostic path referencing (e.g. os.path.join).

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.imread()` couldn't locate your image file i.e drop.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question when I ran the opencv 3.0.1 at windows X64 OS.

When I checked out the code, I found out that `cv2.imread`'s first parameter is incorrect, i.e. the image does not exist.

When I copied the image file to the right path, the code ran OK.

I advise you to make sure that the image file path is correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("D:\Matlab\Images\d.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow("blue", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.