# Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) Qt with OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have a problem to display an image on Qt Creator with OpenCV library.

I have a program that displays an image when a button is pressed. When I run it, it gives me

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.

```
using namespace cv;

void MainWindow::on_start_clicked()
{

    Mat src = imread("C:/Users/Amr/Documents/untitled7/layout.jpeg",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("src",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("src",src);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow("src");
}
```

but when i try this program it works very good

```
using namespace cv;

void MainWindow::on_start_clicked()
{

     Mat src (500,500,CV_8UC3,Scalar(255,0,0));
    namedWindow("src",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("src",src);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow("src");
}
```

I feel that the problem is in the directory but I don't know what it is. I have tried to change `/` to `\` or `//` but still getting this error.

Comment: Test if loading is correct by comparing returned value with `src.data!=NULL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821269/assertion-failed-size-width0-size-height0)

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe. Here it's clear what the error means.. the question is why it doesn't work with the current line of code. Just my two cents...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the path is correct, using `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` doesn't make sense. Use `IMREAD_XXX`:

```
Mat src = imread("C:/Users/Amr/Documents/untitled7/layout.jpeg", IMREAD_COLOR);
```

However, double check the path, and remember that "image.jpeg" is different from "image.jpg". And... are you sure "untitled7" is correct?

Comment: i got the path by copy past, so i'm sure it is correct, i have tried  IMREAD_COLOR instead of CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE  but still getting this error

Comment: i have tested the image loading using (stc.data) and i know now it is not loaded successfully but don't know why

Comment: Have you read my answer? Use IMREAD_COLOR, check the actual extension, the untitled7 doesn't seem right. And... does the image exist?