# opencv read image assertion failed

Tags: python, image, opencv, assertion

I am a newbie to python and opencv.
trying to read image.

here is my code :-

```
import cv2
import numpy
img = cv2.imread('Test1.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

here is the error generated :-

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/68762549-a7cd-401a-4fc4-6547354af396/volume/opencv_1512680491081/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp,
>   line 331 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/vinayak/PycharmProjects/Python_test1/test_img.py", line 4, in
>   
>       cv2.imshow('image',img) cv2.error: /opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/68762549-a7cd-401a-4fc4-6547354af396/volume/opencv_1512680491081/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:331:
>   error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

please help me identify the fault. thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821269/assertion-failed-size-width0-size-height0)

Answer (score 0):

This error means you didn´t loaded the image and img is empty.

There is a known error in imread for cv2. You can try replacing the imread call with this portion :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread('Test1.jpg')
```

matplotlib does not have the same error on cv2.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, this is the right way to load and display an image unsing OpenCV in Python, the additional argument you passed (0) means you're loading the image as grayscale and is the numeric value for the enum cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE

[opencv load image tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

[link to enums](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html)

Just for the sake of completeness, here the basic code I tested

```
    import cv2 as cv

    img = cv.imread('C:\\path\\to\\my\\Image\\image.bmp',0)
    cv.imshow('image',img)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Due to this, the issue is most probably related to the path your're passing to cv.imread function

- Are you sure your image is in the same working directoy you're
  using?(and I bet is not...)
- Did you try to change the relative path you gave with a complete absolute
  path?