# can't open webcam GStreamer gives error (openCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer, webcam

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <opencv2/cv.hpp>

//#include <opencv\highgui.h>
//#include <opencv\cv.h>



using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

    Mat image;
cv::VideoCapture capture(0);      // open the default camera
if(!capture.isOpened())           // check if it succeeded
{
  //...
    cout << "error  error is may ";
} 
    return 0;
}
```

When i pass my default webcam (0) it gives error. If i try string of video something like "test.mp4" it doesnt. I am using Linux Mint and
my cmake was like this
/

```
opt/opencv/release$ cmake -D BUILD_TIFF=ON -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D ENABLE_AVX=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_TBB=ON -D WITH_EIGEN=OFF -D WITH_V4L=OFF -D WITH_VTK=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv_contrib/modules /opt/opencv/
```

Error Message

```
(process:30329): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
```

Comment: Your code is correct, the problem must be with the configuration of your environment. Why do you execute `cmake` from the `/opt/opencv` directory? Can you show your project structure and post your project (not opencv project) `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/

I followed tutorials from this page.

Comment: So don't follow this tutorial. The man is using `root` user all the time and even for that reason only I daresay it's a low quality article (but there are few other flaws). What is wrong with the [official OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)? Just remove all the stuff you have done so far and install OpenCV, then write a code normally. Seriously, OpenCV docs are really clear and executing `mkdir build && cd build`, `cmake ..`, `make`, `sudo make install` seems quite trivial to me.

Comment: its complex and for a starter doesnt tell you what to do exactly. Says  here's some parameters , what am i supposed to with them , i dont even understand it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821269/assertion-failed-size-width0-size-height . Latest reply by indian guy actually works ( opening and looping camera for 4 times) but  WTF no idea why even works. it also doesnt close when click  like infinite loop cameras. Ctrl + c works though. Very interesting case we got here.